# Dynamically change property inside of javascript filter function

Tags: javascript, angular, filter

I want to change the property **d.name** to **d.role** or **d.id** inside of the filter function based on a parameter passed through the parent function. I can't access it inside the filter function though.

```
   const temp = this.temp.filter(function(d) {
   return d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== 
    -1 || !val;
    });
```

What would be the best way to do this? I've done some searching but I can't seem to find a good solution. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Changing array elements inside `.filter()` seems like a *really* questionable idea.

Comment: Also your question is completely unclear. *What* can't you access? How do you know you can't access it? Are you getting an error? If so, what is it? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: You can do this with `closure`s. They are basically functions that can return functions with different parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use square bracket syntax for this, so it becomes

```
   key = 'role'

   const temp = this.temp.filter((d) => {
     return d[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== 
        -1 || !val;
   });
```

Comment: I tried this, 
return d[this.filterType].toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
but I keep getting this error: 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filterType' of undefined     
 
this.filterType is my global variable set to the id, and if I console log it in the parent function, it has the value.

Comment: @cheesydoritosandkale I've updated the answer to use arrow functions. Try that

Comment: @user184994, are we like neurologically connected or something? :D

Comment: Oh I think it didn't work because I was setting it as a global maybe? it worked when I used let!

Comment: @cheesydoritosandkale Actually, the reason it probably didn't work is to do with `this` scoping. The scope of `this` changes inside each enclosing function, however if we use an arrow function, it retains the enclosing scope, so `this` remains defined

Comment: @user184994 You are right - I just tested it and it worked with the arrow function

Answer (score 1):

You can always use another Object Member Access Pattern here.

Keeping `d[keyToFilterOn]` with the value of `keyToFilterOn` as 'role' is similar to doing `d.role`.

So why not doing something like this:

```
let keyToFilterOn = 'role'; // or id
const temp = this.temp.filter(d => {
  return d[keyToFilterOn].toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
});
```

This way, you won't have to create a function for it.

### Alternative

You can create an AngularPipe and then use it in your TypeScript Class:

Here's the `filter`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(temp: any[], filterBy: string, filterValue: any): any {
    if (!filterBy || !filterValue) {
      return input;
    }
    return temp.filter(d => {
      return d[filterBy].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) !== -1 || !filterValue;
    });
  }

}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
import { FilterPipe } from 'path/to/the/pipe';

class YourComponent {

  YourFunction(value) {
    let filteredData = new FilterPipe().transform(this.temp, keyToFilterOn, val);
  }
}
```

Although Angular doesn't really recommend using a `Pipe` for filtering data. But since this is being used inside a class and not in the template, it's fine.

Comment: Oh actually, it didn't work when I used it as a global, but I set it just like you did and it worked!

Comment: Glad it did. I have another approach if you'd like?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your filter function inside other function and simply pass in in the property name on which you want to filter.

**For example :**

```js
let arr = [{name :"xyz", role:"admin"},{name :"xyz", role:"teacher"},{name :"abc", role:"admin"}];

function filterList(arr, prop, val){
  return arr.filter(e=> e[prop] == val);
}

console.log(filterList(arr, "role", "admin" ));
console.log(filterList(arr, "name", "xyz" ));
```